# Passing YouTube player parameters from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, youtube, window.open, window.opener

I have a main window that opens a child window via window.open for the sole purpose of acting as a "pop up window" YouTube player.  The child window page is populated with the Iframe code off of the YouTube developer's page from here:

```
 https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started
```

The parameter I'm trying to pass is the videoID code in the YT player function.

I can put the code in single quotes directly, and the window open / play works.
I can assign the code to a variable, and then assign videoID = variable, and that works.
I can pass the code via window.opener method using variables and that works.

But - if I store a list of ID codes in an array of strings, the code APPEARS to pass correctly from either the parent or child (I've tried storing it on both pages) all the way to the videoID parameter - but the YTplayer always indicates an "error" after loading to a black screen.  It does not matter if the code is assigned to a variable or not before it gets to the function, if it originates from the array, it will not work in the player.  Here is the array declaration, in case I'm missing something.  My experience with Java arrays is limited and they don't seem user friendly...

```
var uTube = new Array(11);
uTube[0] = "";
uTube[1] = "'K9qO3rCmP_Q'";
uTube[2] = "'RkB7rsOeBA0'";
uTube[3] = "";
uTube[4] = "";
uTube[5] = "";
uTube[6] = "";
uTube[7] = "";
uTube[8] = "";
uTube[9] = "";
uTube[10] = "";
```

I verified that the information stored in the array and any variables intervening LOOKS correct by deactivating the function and then doing a document.write to the screen so I could see the values.  As far as I can see, it's all apparently correct, and definitely not working.  I'd like to solve this because calling the correct string from an array after selecting a thumbnail in a gallery seems easier than trying to handle a slew of unrelated variables.

Is it a timing issue related to parsing the array?

Comment: why don't you just do `var uTube = ["", "'K9qO3rCmP_Q'", "'RkB7rsOeBA0'", "", "" ...]` instead of all those lines?

Comment: Ugh nevermind, I am SOOO-O-O stupid...I forgot I added the double string terminators during a debug (which I have to "unassisted" in WebMatrix)...dropped 'em and the show is on.

@Doorknob:  The format is there to make it easy and obvious to update the video codes in the future by someone who didn't write the code (it stands out better).  Over a long period of time, the array will expand slowly to more entries.  I didn't write a database, either, because I'd already done one in this website (This is my first site, my CSS/HTML/Java is self-taught, and I'm experimenting with techniques). Thanx!